# Play PCM stored in EEPROM without microcontroller

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, dac, eeprom

Is it possible to connect digital-to-audio converter with a EEPROM storing PCM data to play that data with a speaker? I am interested in a solution that does not employ any kind of microcontroller. Basically what I need is a low-power circuit driven by 3-3.3v that just plays recorded PCM data. This is for self-educational purpose, not commercial. I do realize that the use of microcontroller is more appropriate here.

Comment: But it's *so easy* with a microcontroller...

Comment: One way would be a clock, binary counter(s), parallel EEPROM and parallel DAC. Lots more chips, wider data path and as Ignacio says easy with a microcontroller. Some parallel chips are pretty old technology, I wouldn't be suprised if a micro would use less power too. Any real reason for avoiding one?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a microcontroller?

Comment: And on that "pretty old technology" angle, not sure you'd find those in a 3.3v format.

Comment: For how long? There are single-chip solutions that record maybe a minute of speech and replay it at the push of a button.

Comment: No MCU, Ok. Do you accept FPGA?

Comment: The question is of an educational purpose, not commercial. I do realize that the use of micro is far easier.

Comment: Seems quite simple with standard logic chips; an ADC & DAC to covert, a clock circuit, counter for addresses, some miscellaneous supporting logic for play/pause/record/stop.

Comment: also in defence of the original poster, sometimes it is good to actually know how things work or can work instead of always taking the simplest way, asking yourself questions like how could things be done differently, is that which is required to truly help society get further. otherwise if only combining existing stuf in the normal way you only get small improvements or just products. microcontrollers came just because someone asked itself if they couldn't do it in another way, most new things come from someons asking a question or making a  suggestion most others find stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe was popular in the past in the guise of "digital waveform generator".

http://technologyinterface.nmsu.edu/Spring07/35_Moselhpour-Waveform_Gen/index.pdf

http://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-75/75G.PDF

http://www.sm0vpo.com/eprom/epromosc.htm

... you would need to update for modern EEPROM and 3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a fun thing to do and an interesting challenge.  It isn't likely to be the lowest power way of doing it though.  There are a lot of low power micros available.

What you need, one way or another, is an address generator.  You could do this with old style logic or a micro.  Generating the address is the job that the micro is doing.  You could also use a cpld, but this isn't likely to save you any power compared to a low power micro either.

Your system will need a clock and a micro may well include one.  This will save you yet more components and power compared to discrete components.